# Validate empty request

Tags: spring, spring-boot, validate-request

I am developing a SpringBoot Application. For a POST end-point, there is NO request body to be passed. My service is working fine. But its also working when I pass some values in the body of the request. **How can I validate and return a BAD REQUEST if something is passed in the body of request which should ideally remain empty for this request?**

```
*@RequestMapping(value = "/sample/customers", method = POST)
public Customer session() {
    return customerService.getCustomer();
}*
```

Comment: Why use a POST when there is no body? Why not GET?

Comment: maybe  you can use `@Null String body ` as argument

Answer (score 0):

You should not use **POST** for data retrieval.

You'll need 2 methods. Here is an example code for the save:

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CREATED)
@RequestMapping(value = "/sample/customers", method = POST)
public Customer save(@RequestBody CustomerRequestDto customerRequestDto) {
    return customerService.save(customerRequestDto);
}
```